# Migrate from VS2005 to VS 2010 directly

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2010

Our project is currently developed in C#2 , VS2005.
We were thinking of migrating to VS2008 and C#3.

Do you think it might be a better idea to move directly to VS2010 instead?
We do not plan to release the new version till the end of next year.

> Is there any advantage in moving from vs05 to vs08 and then moving to vs10?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well [this post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=467761) implies you can, but certain features of certain projects might get broken:

> When you upgrade certain solutions from VS2005 to VS2010, the solution explorer layout can become broken. Some files move up the filter hierarchy. In our large solution, a hundred or so files ended up in the root of solution explorer.
>
> It only seems to affect solutions where the solution explorer filter nesting is more than one deep, the files are not compiled (like headers), and they're excluded from the build in some configs.

Though an answer indicates it was fixed:

> We have verified that the header file now gets placed under subfolder rather than directly the header filter. The fix should be available in the next public release of VS2010 (Beta2).

To answer your other point. One advantage of going via VS 2008 is that you can make that migration now (assuming you don't want to risk beta software) and start using the features of C# 3 straight away.

Comment: +1 Migration for C# projects will always be easy be it VS2005 to VS2008 or VS2010. But if you have any VC++ projects, I would prefer migrating to VS2008 & then to VS2010 (after say SP1 is out) cause Microsoft has a habit of having a lot of documented & undocumented breaking changes in unmanaged side.

Comment: No VC++ projects. But the solution does have some thing like 30 projects. I think I'll give it a shot and see how it goes.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 comes with a "Go-Live" license, so if you are ok dealing with beta software, then why not?  I have tried it at work myself, while the other developers continue on 2008, but I have to be careful with the project files, to not check in changes, etc....  I don't use it all the time, yet, because it's a memory hog, but other than that performance is a lot better.

There are also a lot of features that are worth the upgrade.  The text editor is in WPF now and scales nicely with a ctrl-click and I find I use it a lot.  There are a lot of new addins being built to integrate with the UI because the new framework for the code editor exposes a new addin model that is much easier to develop against.

Being able to split windows across multiple montiors in a more flexible way is great.

If you go for the "Ultimate" versions, there are a ton of new architecture and modeling tools and tools for exploring code.  I love the ability to generate a sequence diagram from some method and use that while I am reading some unfamiliar code.  Works great.

The list goes on really, I have barely scratched the surface, so yeah move on if you want to learn how to use the new stuff, and no one is stopping you, go for it.

Comment: Nice listing of additional features of VS2010, but you don't answer his main question "Is there any advantage in moving from vs05 to vs08 and then moving to vs10?"